# Android Game Client, Achievement unlock popup not shown over the Fragment

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am registering the popup view as below:

```
GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(activity, googleSignInAccount);
gamesClient.setViewForPopups(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

In the main activity, but when the achievement is unlocked from the full-screen fragment dialog, no popup was shown, but in the activity, it is shown properly.

Please help to show the popup over the fragment as well.

I have tried to register the popup view from the fragment but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just do nothing and delete your `setViewForPopups` call. It is not necessary.

Comment: But by doing this, I even don't get and unlock or welcome back popup in the game.

Comment: Then you have some other code disabling it. I don't call this method and for me all popups work.

Comment: Can you help me out to find what blocking it, also did all popup works for fullscreen activity and fullscreen dialogFragments?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_pop_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(MainActivity.this, 
 GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
        gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.container_pop_up));

        Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .unlock(getString(R.string.achievement_example));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need xml reference. Use this:

```
GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(this, Objects.requireNonNull(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)));
gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
gamesClient.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```